# Can't open anything on Command Prompt

Tags: windows-10, command-prompt, onedrive, desktop, cd

Today I was trying to get started with Visual Studio Code, but my command prompt had a major problem.

I was trying to do the >cd Desktop command, but it didn't work. (I tried using cmd prompt with admin too)

I also tried the >cd OneDrive command before desktop, but it also didn't work

I then tried to open anything, and it just says **"The System cannot find the path specified."**

I have a windows 10 Surface Laptop 3,  please help.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. Apparently, it must have been some glitch, because when I restarted my device it was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. but it is resolved now
check the cmd in the C:->windows->system32 ->cmd
if it is not present there then copy the cmd where it is currently present(In my case it was present in C: -> windows->SysWOW64  ) to the system32 location

It will surely work

As a shortcut you can also use Windows+R key  .Write cmd in the find place .Then command prompt will open :)